# Itext TextRenderInfo different behavior for different pdf

Tags: itext

I am using 
***itext*** -> **LocationTextExtractionStrategy** for retrieving the text from PDF, 
I have read 2 different pdf and debug them
For 1st one i have found  in
 `public void renderText(TextRenderInfo renderInfo)`

method text is rendering with word
e.g: I have a pdf with some content

`ACCOUNT TYPE     A/C. BALANCE (I)    FIXED DEPOSITS (LINKED) BAL. (II)`

then renderText method rendering text in a loop like:
**ACCOUNT TYPE** then **A/C. BALANCE (I)** and then **FIXED DEPOSITS (LINKED) BAL. (II)**

Now when i the debugging 2 pdf with content and it's rendering with letter e.g i have content:

**Date  Details  Withdrawals**

then renderText method rendering text in a loop:
**D** then **a** then **t** then **e** and so on

I am wondering how it renders the text(means some time iterate with word and some time with a group of words and some time iterate with just a letter )?

Comment: Bhushan, did my answer explain *"how it renders the text"* or do you still have questions?

Answer (score 0):

> how it renders the text(means some time iterate with word and some time with a group of words and some time iterate with just a letter )?

The iText parsing framework forwards the atomic strings used in arguments of PDF text drawing operations.

Thus,  if the PDF draws text letter by letter, you'll receive one `TextRenderInfo` instance per letter. If it draws text word by word, you'll receive one instance per word.

Comment: hi mkl, is there any way to find out the details of pdf draws strategy, any method or anything else which will help me to find out the rendering per letter or word.

Comment: *is there any way to find out the details of pdf draws strategy* - yes, simply analyse what you retrieve via `renderText`.